# Is there a standardized way to assign a label to the symbol of a chemical element (in a published work)?

Tags: reference-request, notation

When referring to a particular atom, both in text and when using a graphical representation, several conventions are being applied.

In the field of crystallography an arabic numeral either follows the element symbol without any space, e.g. $\mathrm{C}42$ for carbon atom number $42$ (usually assigned during solve/refine routine by SHELX), or is being placed in braces, e.g. $\mathrm{C}(42).$
Sometimes hydrogens attached to the same carbon atom inherit its number and receive an additional letter, e.g. $\mathrm{H42c}$ for the third hydrogen in  $\mathrm{C42}$ methyl group.

In NMR spectroscopy an element is normally labeled with a script-sized symbol (arabic number or lowercase letter) in the bottom right corner, e.g. $\ce{H_3}$ or $\ce{H_c}.$
Mestrelab Mnova places numerical labels underneath the element symbol, e.g. $\underset{3}{\ce{H}}$, or directly in place of the element if the symbol for the latter is hidden (carbon, in most cases): ${\scriptsize 3}.$

These labeling schemes used in both instrumental methods (which I cherry-picked solely for the illustrative purposes) seem to work OK in a sense that they are compatible with expanded AZE-notation required to depict any element and its attributes, such as chemical symbol $\ce{El},$ mass number $A,$ atomic number $Z,$ oxidation number O.N., charge $q$ and number of atoms of given kind $x$:

$$\Large\ce{\overset{\text{O.N.}}{^{$A$}_{$Z$}El^{$q$}_x}}$$

and won't cause any confusion (except for $\ce{H_3},$ maybe).
However, it would be nice to know whether there is a standardized way to attribute a label to an element that can be uniformly displayed and recognized (main text, titles, structures, illustrations etc.).
Does such robust labeling scheme exist?

P.S. If you are a software developer and read this, also feel free to comment or add an answer as to which labeling scheme you've came up with for calling out a particular atom.

Comment: IUPAC's green book "Quantities Units and Symbols in Physical Chemistry" might be worth a look. It is a 165-paged book.

Comment: @M.Farooq Already did. According to the Green Book, labels (in general) must be typed in upright typeface, that's all I found.

Comment: I can imagine that this can become a headache for a reader if the numbering scheme is not obvious, but that does not appear to be a consideration in this question. To draw a comparison, protein sequences are numbered N->C ie Ala42 is the C-terminal residue in the A$\beta$(1-42) peptide. This rarely is a problem although numbering conventions may refer to the original gene rather than a specific construct such as the A$\beta$ in question. But since the sequences are linear the numbering convention is otherwise clear. Now consider branching and rings in compounds and the story changes.

Comment: In any case your question is about convention, not about the best way to do this for the sake of clarity. I would say stick to the  crystallography convention but if the molecule is complex provide a structure file or figure with numbering.

Comment: @BuckThorn Yeah, I have the same feeling that crystallographic notation would be easier to maintain. And I actually do care about reader's ergonomics, but I'd put standards/recommendations/guidelines first, if there are any, to avoid confusion and develop a coherent labeling scheme. Ideally, the one that is interdisciplinary understood:)

Comment: Well, if IUPAC has not dictated a final opinion on the subject (or doesn't seem to care enough to put clear guidelines where people can readily find them) then maybe clarity should be your guideline. I don't know who beside IUPAC can be expected to provide official guidance (or should be payed close attention to) on the matter. If your molecule is complex, then aggregating opinion from others might be a valuable alternative.